# SQL Server (t-sql) setting to trim trailing spaces from CHAR-like columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We're using PHP PDO with sqlsrv driver to connect to SQL Server. When selecting char(x) (or like) columns from the database, trailing spaces are always added to such columns (to string length x). This appears to be by design, but it can by quite annoying.

Is there some server-level or session-level setting to force SQL Server to rtrim all such columns upon select?

I know I can manually add in rtrim for all char-like columns, but it's annoying because I have to inspect whether a column is a char(x) or a varchar(x) since in the latter, trailing spaces might be meaningful. Also, we could change all char to varchar (but alas we are currently unable to do that).

Thanks.

Comment: Trailing spaces on a `(n)char` column _might_ be meaningful, too. :) But it's often just a poor datatype choice way back at design time. I think you're stuck though. Right padding a `(n)char` column is the intended behavior (assuming ANSI_PADDING was ON at column/table creation), and I don't think there's a way to override that on data retrieval. Other than, of course, the painful `RTRIM` wrappers.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such option in SQL Server.